# java spark, using max value of a column in another without breaking deferred execution

Tags: java, apache-spark

With Java Spark, I have a `Dataset<Row>` with a  Column of unique numeric IDs.

```
| Id |
|  1 |
|  5 |
|  2 |
```

For each of those rows I generate several rows in anothe Dataframe. The Ids are not scrambled by the transformation.

```
| Id |
|  1 |
|  1 |
|  1 |
|  5 |
|  2 |
|  2 |
```

Since Ids are supposed to be unique, I need to regenerate a new set of Id. However I need to keep a trace of the transformation, so I keep the old ids and try to generate a second Id column with Ids.

To make things simpler for the human consuming the data and prevent confusion, I want those newer ids to follow two rules :

- New Id and Old Id should not overlap
- New Ids need to be consecutive for a same old Id

For example a valid result could be :

```
|New_Id   | Old_Id |
| 59404   |  1     |
| 59405   |  1     |
| 59406   |  1     |
| 493     |  5     |
| 3       |  2     |
| 4       |  2     |
```

To achieve this I tried

```
df.withColumnRenamed("Id", "Old_Id").withColumn("New_Id", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

But the `New_Id` column produced is just consecutive integers from zero. Which satisfies my second rule but not the first one.

```
|New_Id   | Old_Id |
| 0       |  1     |
| 1       |  1     |
| 2       |  1     |
| 3       |  5     |
| 4       |  2     |
| 5       |  2     |
```

To fix this, I thought of adding the max value of the `Old_Id` to my `monotonically_increasing_id`

```
Column maxId = lit(df.select("Id").agg(max("Id")).head().getLong(0)));
Dataset<Row> result = df.withColumnRenamed("Id", "Old_Id").withColumn("New_Id", monotonically_increasing_id().plus(maxId));
```

It produces the expected result but is this the correct way to achieve this ? Is there a simpler or built-in way ? In terms of lazy evaluation/deferred execution, does this goes through my dataset once or twice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably shouldn't use monotonically_increasing_id for an actual id generation, the next time you run that query you'll get the same id's again.  If you want unique id's use something that produces them like Sparks uuid or [unique_id](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/0.1.1/advanced/rowIdFunctions/#guaranteed-unique-id-how).  If your data has combinations of fields forming a primary key you could also hash on them to produce a data driven key.

Regarding your last code snippet that will force all of the df to be evaluated for max("id"), so you evaluate twice.  There is no other way to use this approach, but per above I'd argue it's possibly not a good approach for you.